# how can i send a xml through a url

Tags: php, xml

I have a php page say ***`test.php`***

Here i am creating an xml

```
$xmlVariable = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<signupInfo>
<address>
      <address>1 Infinite Loop</address>
      <city>Cupertino</city>
      <state>CA</state>
      <zip>99999</zip>
    </address>

</signupInfo>
```

Now i need to send it to a destination`(eg:https://destination.cm/fg)`

**How can i send this xml?**

Comment: It depends on the format that the destination expects it in. HTTP PUT request? Form encoded data with the XML being the value for a given field name? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

With cURL

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
if (!$curl_handle) {
  die('fail to initialize');
}

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

//target URL setup
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://destination.cm/fg');
//mime type setup, change if necessary
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//here you assign the body of your request
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlVariable);

$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);

if (curl_errno($curl_handle)) {
  die(curl_error($curl_handle));            
}

printf("Received :\n%s", $response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.Let me check with that

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your xml data is not very long,but it's not suggested that you send data using this way.It refers to security problem.So use POST instead of get

forget this post,I get something wrong...sorry :(

Comment: How is post more secure than get?

Comment: And who said anything about GET?

Comment: how can i use POST here, could you explain more?